# MYSQL - COUNT() NULL Values

Tags: mysql

This has been racking my head. I've scoured the internet (including this place) and can't find a solution. So as a last resort I was hoping the good people of this forum might be able to help me out.

I have two tables:

```
TableA
Order_detailsID 
OrderID
TitleID
Return_date

TableB
TitleID
Title_name
Quantity_in_stock
```

And would like to run a query that shows the remaining 'Quantity_in_stock'.

If the 'Return_date' is set to NULL then it means the item is currently out -- so I have been trying to use the count() function for the NULL values and subtract it from the 'Quantity_in_stock'.

This is the script I have so far:

```
DELIMITER //
 CREATE PROCEDURE InStock()
BEGIN

Select TableB.TitleID,
TableB.Title_name,
TableB.Quantity_in_stock AS 'Total_Stock',
COUNT(TableA.return_date IS NULL) AS 'Rented_Out',
TableB.Quantity_in_stock - COUNT(TableA.return_date IS NULL) AS 'Remaining Stock'
From TableB
LEFT JOIN TableA
ON TableA.TitleID = TableB.TitleID
GROUP BY TableB.TitleID;

END//
```

This works if there is one of more of the TitleIDs at NULL, however if there are no values at NULL, then the Count() is still returning a value of 1 when it should be 0.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of:

```
COUNT(TableA.return_date IS NULL)
```

use this:

```
SUM(CASE 
        WHEN TableA.TitleID IS NULL THEN 0
        WHEN TableA.return_date IS NOT NULL THEN 0
        ELSE 1
      END)
```

The problem with the `TableA.return_date IS NULL` predicate is that it's true in two completely different situations:

1. When there is no matching record in `TableA`
2. When there is a matching record but `TableA.return_date` value of this exact record is `NULL`.

Using the `CASE` expression you can differentiate between these two cases.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.

That is working for TitleIDs that don't appear at all in TableA. However, TitleIDs that do appear in TableA but have a non-NULL return_date (a date) are still being counted. I only want to subtract the NULL values from the quantity.

Comment: Appreciate the help again, but I'm afraid I'm still getting two issues:

1) If the TitleID doesn't appear in TableA at all then it's still counting it once and deducting 1 from TableB.Quantity_in_stock.

2) If the TitleID appears in TableA with a non-NULL return_date, then it's also counting these.

Comment: @Gary866 Can you provide some sample data along with required result set?

Comment: @Gary866 Please check the edit I made. I'm using `SUM` instead of `COUNT`. You can also see a use case [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a18adb/4).

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos Hi, Giorgos, why not shorten your sum expression to the following?  `TableB.Quantity_in_stock - SUM(if (TableA.return_date IS NOT NULL, 1,0)) AS 'Remaining Stock'`

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos Bingo! That works! Thank you for the help.

Comment: @Ben it seems that values that don't appear in TableA as considered NULL, so your script adds a 1 to them and include them to the SUM(). I appreciate the response nonetheless.

Comment: @Gary866 Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

I will like to mention a simple concept here, just keep counting the rows when that particular column is `null`.

```
select count(*) from table_name where column_name is null
```